# Is there a common time range widget for zooming in multiple charts (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am using Highcharts-Vue and I have multiple stockChart charts that I want to synchronize their x-axis zoom. So, when I zoom in one, all the others zoom at the same region.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hi @help, There is no such widget. You need to get a chart reference and call `setExtremes`. Example in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6Lat7con/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: I have tried that. But, it somehow doesn't work. Any other suggestion in mind?

Comment: There is no other way. Could you create a live example in codesandbox to allow me to check what is not working? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-ttner

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Could you create a minimal live reproduction of the problem?